# How to create a new list in R merging each data frame with previous data frame into the same list

Tags: r

Hi everybody I am trying to solve a little problem with a list of data frames in R. I have a list of data frames with a structure like this:

```
list
$a1
   ID Mount s1
1 001     1  1
2 002     2  1
3 003     3  1
4 004     4  1
5 005     5  1
6 006     6  1
7 007     7  1
8 009     8  1
9 010     9  1

$a2
    ID Mount s2
1  001     1  2
2  002     2  2
3  003     3  2
4  004     4  2
5  005     5  2
6  006     6  2
7  007     7  2
8  009     8  2
9  010     9  2
10 011    10  2
11 012    11  2

$a3
    ID Mount s3
1  001     1  3
2  002     2  3
3  003     3  3
4  004     4  3
5  005     5  3
6  006     6  3
7  007     7  3
8  009     8  3
9  010     9  3
10 011    10  3
11 012    11  3
12 013    11  3
13 014    11  3

$a4
    ID Mount s4
1  001     1  4
2  002     2  4
3  003     3  4
4  004     4  4
5  005     5  4
6  006     6  4
7  007     7  4
8  009     8  4
9  010     9  4
10 011    10  4
11 012    11  4
12 013    11  4
13 014    11  4
14 015    12  4
15 016    12  4

$a5
    ID Mount s5
1  001     1  5
2  002     2  5
3  003     3  5
4  004     4  5
5  005     5  5
6  006     6  5
7  007     7  5
8  009     8  5
9  010     9  5
10 011    10  5
11 012    11  5
12 013    11  5
13 014    11  5
14 015    12  5
15 016    12  5
16 017    14  5
17 018    14  5
```

My question is how can I get merged each data frame with previuos data frames in the same list for example `a1` will get merged with `a1`, `a2` will get merged with `a1`, `a3` will get merged with `a2` and `a1`, `a4` will get merged `a3`, `a2` and `a1` and `a5` will get merged `a4`, `a3`, `a2` and `a1`. I was doing this merge considering `ID` var to add `s` in each data frame. I want to get something like this in a new list:

```
list.merged
$a1
   ID Mount s1
1 001     1  1
2 002     2  1
3 003     3  1
4 004     4  1
5 005     5  1
6 006     6  1
7 007     7  1
8 009     8  1
9 010     9  1

$a2
    ID Mount s2 s1
1  001     1  2 1
2  002     2  2 1
3  003     3  2 1
4  004     4  2 1
5  005     5  2 1
6  006     6  2 1
7  007     7  2 1
8  009     8  2 1
9  010     9  2 1
10 011    10  2 NA
11 012    11  2 NA

$a3
    ID Mount s3 s2 s1 
1  001     1  3 2  1
2  002     2  3 2  1
3  003     3  3 2  1
4  004     4  3 2  1
5  005     5  3 2  1
6  006     6  3 2  1
7  007     7  3 2  1
8  009     8  3 2  1
9  010     9  3 2  1
10 011    10  3 2  NA
11 012    11  3 2  NA
12 013    11  3 NA NA
13 014    11  3 NA NA

$a4
    ID Mount s4 s3 s2 s1
1  001     1  4 3  2  1
2  002     2  4 3  2  1
3  003     3  4 3  2  1
4  004     4  4 3  2  1
5  005     5  4 3  2  1
6  006     6  4 3  2  1
7  007     7  4 3  2  1
8  009     8  4 3  2  1
9  010     9  4 3  2  1
10 011    10  4 3  2  NA
11 012    11  4 3  2  NA
12 013    11  4 3  NA NA
13 014    11  4 3  NA NA
14 015    12  4 NA NA NA
15 016    12  4 NA NA NA

$a5
    ID Mount s5 s4 s3 s2 s1
1  001     1  5 4  3  2  1
2  002     2  5 4  3  2  1
3  003     3  5 4  3  2  1
4  004     4  5 4  3  2  1
5  005     5  5 4  3  2  1
6  006     6  5 4  3  2  1
7  007     7  5 4  3  2  1
8  009     8  5 4  3  2  1
9  010     9  5 4  3  2  1
10 011    10  5 4  3  2  NA
11 012    11  5 4  3  2  NA
12 013    11  5 4  3  NA NA
13 014    11  5 4  3  NA NA
14 015    12  5 4  NA NA NA
15 016    12  5 4  NA NA NA
16 017    14  5 NA NA NA NA
17 018    14  5 NA NA NA NA
```

I was using the function `Reduce` with `merge` inside but in a first moment I got merged only `a1` with all data frames in `list`. I used the next function to make this:

```
list.merged=Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y[,c(1,3)],by.x="ID",by.y="ID",all.x=TRUE),list)
```

But I got a data frame instead of a list with the merged data frames. I don't know if it is possible to redefine last code to apply to each data frame in `list` because I used the same code with `lapply()` but I got error. The `dput` version of `list` is the next:

```
structure(list(a1 = structure(list(ID = c("001", "002", "003", 
"004", "005", "006", "007", "009", "010"), Mount = c(1, 2, 3, 
4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), s1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), .Names = c("ID", 
"Mount", "s1"), row.names = c(NA, 9L), class = "data.frame"), 
    a2 = structure(list(ID = c("001", "002", "003", "004", "005", 
    "006", "007", "009", "010", "011", "012"), Mount = c(1, 2, 
    3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11), s2 = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2)), .Names = c("ID", "Mount", "s2"), row.names = c(NA, 
    11L), class = "data.frame"), a3 = structure(list(ID = c("001", 
    "002", "003", "004", "005", "006", "007", "009", "010", "011", 
    "012", "013", "014"), Mount = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 
    10, 11, 11, 11), s3 = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
    3, 3)), .Names = c("ID", "Mount", "s3"), row.names = c(NA, 
    13L), class = "data.frame"), a4 = structure(list(ID = c("001", 
    "002", "003", "004", "005", "006", "007", "009", "010", "011", 
    "012", "013", "014", "015", "016"), Mount = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 
    5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12), s4 = c(4, 4, 4, 4, 
    4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4)), .Names = c("ID", "Mount", 
    "s4"), row.names = c(NA, 15L), class = "data.frame"), a5 = structure(list(
        ID = c("001", "002", "003", "004", "005", "006", "007", 
        "009", "010", "011", "012", "013", "014", "015", "016", 
        "017", "018"), Mount = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
        11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 14, 14), s5 = c(5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
        5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5)), .Names = c("ID", "Mount", 
    "s5"), row.names = c(NA, 17L), class = "data.frame")), .Names = c("a1", 
"a2", "a3", "a4", "a5"))
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does adding `accumulate=TRUE` to the end of your `Reduce` call give you what you want?

Comment: Dear @thelatemail but I don't know how to use `Reduce` for each element in `list` when I add `accumulate=TRUE` I got one data frame only with the first element. Can you help me with that please.

Comment: I get 5 data.frames in a list using `accumulate=TRUE` - check your results.

Comment: Dear @thelatemail you have the reason but the option `all.x=TRUE` is not having effect I am not getting `NA` and that is neccesary. Is it possible tosolve it?

Comment: `Reduce` function (surprisingly) doesn't have ability to take in more arguments for the input function

Comment: Dear @AnandaMahto your solution works with this code I solved my problem `listag=Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y[,c(1,3)],by.x="ID",by.y="ID",all=TRUE), list,accumulate=TRUE)
`

Comment: Dear @AnandaMahto only a little question `all=TRUE` keep all `ID` variable in each data frame and what is the difference with `all.x=TRUE`. I don't have a clear idea about this.

Comment: Dear @AnandaMahto little question is `merge()` in R equal to vlookup in excel or how is possible to adapt `merge()` to work equal to vlookup

Comment: Ok no problem @AnandaMahto but is so strange I used your solution with `merge` over data frames with more rows but I don't get the same result. maybe the order in `merge` could be a problem or merge for each observation in x look for in all observations in y to add the merged variables.

Answer (score 1):

You can write inline function in `Reduce` to pass `all=TRUE` argument to `merge`.

So if you data is in list `LL` (Don't name your objects `list` as it is also a function in R)

```
Reduce(f = function(x, y) merge(x, y, all = TRUE), LL, accumulate = T)
## [[1]]
##    ID Mount s1
## 1 001     1  1
## 2 002     2  1
## 3 003     3  1
## 4 004     4  1
## 5 005     5  1
## 6 006     6  1
## 7 007     7  1
## 8 009     8  1
## 9 010     9  1
## 
## [[2]]
##     ID Mount s1 s2
## 1  001     1  1  2
## 2  002     2  1  2
## 3  003     3  1  2
## 4  004     4  1  2
## 5  005     5  1  2
## 6  006     6  1  2
## 7  007     7  1  2
## 8  009     8  1  2
## 9  010     9  1  2
## 10 011    10 NA  2
## 11 012    11 NA  2
## 
## [[3]]
##     ID Mount s1 s2 s3
## 1  001     1  1  2  3
## 2  002     2  1  2  3
## 3  003     3  1  2  3
## 4  004     4  1  2  3
## 5  005     5  1  2  3
## 6  006     6  1  2  3
## 7  007     7  1  2  3
## 8  009     8  1  2  3
## 9  010     9  1  2  3
## 10 011    10 NA  2  3
## 11 012    11 NA  2  3
## 12 013    11 NA NA  3
## 13 014    11 NA NA  3
## 
## [[4]]
##     ID Mount s1 s2 s3 s4
## 1  001     1  1  2  3  4
## 2  002     2  1  2  3  4
## 3  003     3  1  2  3  4
## 4  004     4  1  2  3  4
## 5  005     5  1  2  3  4
## 6  006     6  1  2  3  4
## 7  007     7  1  2  3  4
## 8  009     8  1  2  3  4
## 9  010     9  1  2  3  4
## 10 011    10 NA  2  3  4
## 11 012    11 NA  2  3  4
## 12 013    11 NA NA  3  4
## 13 014    11 NA NA  3  4
## 14 015    12 NA NA NA  4
## 15 016    12 NA NA NA  4
## 
## [[5]]
##     ID Mount s1 s2 s3 s4 s5
## 1  001     1  1  2  3  4  5
## 2  002     2  1  2  3  4  5
## 3  003     3  1  2  3  4  5
## 4  004     4  1  2  3  4  5
## 5  005     5  1  2  3  4  5
## 6  006     6  1  2  3  4  5
## 7  007     7  1  2  3  4  5
## 8  009     8  1  2  3  4  5
## 9  010     9  1  2  3  4  5
## 10 011    10 NA  2  3  4  5
## 11 012    11 NA  2  3  4  5
## 12 013    11 NA NA  3  4  5
## 13 014    11 NA NA  3  4  5
## 14 015    12 NA NA NA  4  5
## 15 016    12 NA NA NA  4  5
## 16 017    14 NA NA NA NA  5
## 17 018    14 NA NA NA NA  5
##
```